# Update model nested attributes with composite key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I have a model with one_to_many relatioship:

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :work_right_holders
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_right_holders, allow_destroy: true
end

class WorkRightHolder < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :work_id, :right_holder_id, :role

  belongs_to :work
  belongs_to :right_holder
end
```

When I try to update a `work` with nested attributes, it create new instances of object in the relationship, instead of updating the existing based on their primary key:

```
work.update(
  {"work_right_holders_attributes"=>
    {
     "0"=>{ "role"=>"Author", 
            "right_holder_id"=>"2", 
            "work_id"=>work.id, 
            "share"=>"11"
           }
     }
  }
)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you updating now ? The syntax I had shown you that way ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the collection object id, like this:

```
work.update(
  {"work_right_holders_attributes"=>
    {
     "0"=>{ "role"=>"Author", 
            "right_holder_id"=>"2", 
            "work_id"=>work.id, 
            "share"=>"11",
            "id" => [work.id, "2", "Author"]
           }
     }
  }
)
```

This should work.

**obs: in Rails 4.1.1 there is a bug an this does not work, but in Rails 4.2.1 it is working**