# Nested form for association with multiple keys and uniqueness fails on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, composite-key

I have two models associated by a link table that has no id field, but a composite key [product_id, product_set_id].

I have a uniqueness validation on them.

I am trying to set up a nested form, however I noticed the following issue: when updating, it seems activerecord is instead trying to create a new entry and thus it fails.

For example, this a sample parameter hash sent to a patch:

```
Parameters: {"product_set"=>{"name"=>"Marea", "created_by_id"=>"1", "product_product_sets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"product_id"=>"420", "product_set_id"=>"4", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"product_id"=>"423", "product_set_id"=>"4", "_destroy"=>"0"}}}, "commit"=>"Atualizar", "id"=>"4"}
```

I have read somewhere that when there is no :id in the parameters AR presumes it has to create a new record... but how can I tell it to not try to create a new one?

```
validates :product_set_id, uniqueness: { scope: :product_id, message: "This product is already part of this set." }
```

EDIT:

Models:

```
class ProductProductSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :product_set
  validates :product_set_id, uniqueness: { scope: :product_id, message: "This product is already part of this set." }
end

class ProductSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :created_by, class_name: 'User',  foreign_key: 'created_by_id'
  has_many :product_product_sets, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products, :join_table => :product_product_sets
  # has_many :products, through: :product_product_sets, source: :product

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_product_sets, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

product_sets_controller.rb

```
def product_set_params
  params.require(:product_set).permit(:name, :created_by_id, product_product_sets_attributes: [:product_id, :product_set_id, '_destroy'])
end
```

View (not finished of course):

```
= simple_form_for(@product_set) do |f|
    - if @product_set.errors.any?
        .alert.alert-danger
            %ul
                - @product_set.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                    %li= msg
    .form-inputs
        .form-group
            = f.input :name, class: 'form-control'
            = f.association :created_by, class: 'form-control'
            / = text_field_tag 'product_set[product_ids][]', nil, { multiple: true, class: "form-control" }
            / = link_to 'add', 'javascript:void(0);', id: "add_link"
        .existing-products
            = f.fields_for( :product_product_sets, include_id: false ) do |builder| 
                = image_tag builder.object.product.image.url(:thumb)
                = builder.hidden_field :product_id
                = builder.hidden_field :product_set_id
                = builder.check_box :_destroy
                = builder.label :_destroy, "Remove Product"
```

Comment: Can you add the models or at least the relevant chunks? It kind of hard to get a good grip of your relations.

Answer (score 1):

In your update action/params hash I think you need to be passing the collection object id as an array perhaps. Something like this perhaps?

```
 "product_product_sets_attributes"=> { 
    "id" => [product.id, product_set.id]
 }
```

---

My understanding is limited, but I think that as Rails does not support Composite Keys by default you would definitely require the `composite keys gem` and would then require the following style of syntax in your model???

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_keys = :some_id,:some_other_id
end
```

Interested to understand more if this is not the case though.

---

Comment: Okay, that is one step further, however now I get the following error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find ProductProductSet with ID=["454", "4"] for ProductSet with ID=4)` which is weird because the log shows this query being issued: `CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "product_product_sets".* FROM "product_product_sets" WHERE "product_product_sets"."product_set_id" = 4 AND "product_product_sets"."product_id" = 0`

Comment: Did you see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674468/update-model-nested-attributes-with-composite-key-in-rails? May be helpful to solve this.